# Augmented reality on android

Tags: android, image-processing, 3d, augmented-reality, face-detection

I've just started to develop a project as face detection in the base of augmented reality on android phone. And am new to AR(augmented reality) as so far I contributed and evaluated algorithms for facial determinants but I don't have any idea regarding AR and wanna implement AR in my project So could you experts kindly tell me, where to start and and do I need any additional tools to create AR application( /do I've to add any plugins on IDE(eclipse))? or is there is any other IDE works better than eclipse for AR? please check the below link and give your comments because my projects is completely seems as given link below,

http://www.readwriteweb.com/archives/recognizr_facial_recognition_coming_to_android_phones.php

http://www.blackweb20.com/2010/03/01/recognizr-facial-recognition-on-android/#.TzNswE7xodM

thank you!

Answer (score 0):

AR implementation itself is easy.  It is basically just an overlay over preview picture, and you can put whatever you like on this overlay.  One working example is contained  in this project:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/javaocr/

( there are countles others )

Tricky parts  starts from here. For face recognition one typically uses Haar transformation,  and there are implementations in OpenCV (and also countles others)  - but it is questionable if you can it performant enough  in android java code,  to be really usefull ( you wil have to do it in native code ).  And this is only face recognition - it says you - "hey dude, here is the face. maybe" - not identification.

As for IDE,  I prefer IntelliJ IDEA as it is just better java ide (somebody will lynch me right now for it ;) ), and it has better android support.  But this is commercial product (free comminity edition is available for free, and individual license is not that expensive)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. And also I want to know IntelliJ IDEA needs artoolkit? or basically we need to endover the plugins or packages to be installed in IDEs for AR? else can I just start to code without any preemptive packages or plugins packages regards AR

Answer (score 0):

you can try this code:

```
    public class FaceDetectionActivity extends Activity 
   {
     /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
     {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setContentView(R.layout.main);
    setContentView(new MyView(this));
   }

private class MyView extends View
{
    private Bitmap myBitmap;
    private int width, height;
    private FaceDetector.Face[] detectedFaces;
    private int NUMBER_OF_FACES=4;
    private FaceDetector faceDetector;
    private int NUMBER_OF_FACE_DETECTED;
    private float eyeDistance;

    public MyView(Context context) 
    {
        super(context);
        BitmapFactory.Options bitmapFatoryOptions=new BitmapFactory.Options();
        bitmapFatoryOptions.inPreferredConfig=Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;
        myBitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.faces,bitmapFatoryOptions);
        width=myBitmap.getWidth();
        height=myBitmap.getHeight();
        detectedFaces=new FaceDetector.Face[NUMBER_OF_FACES];
        faceDetector=new FaceDetector(width,height,NUMBER_OF_FACES);
        NUMBER_OF_FACE_DETECTED=faceDetector.findFaces(myBitmap, detectedFaces);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        canvas.drawBitmap(myBitmap, 0,0, null);
        Paint myPaint = new Paint();
        myPaint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        myPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE); 
        myPaint.setStrokeWidth(3);

        for(int count=0;count<NUMBER_OF_FACE_DETECTED;count++)
        {
            Face face=detectedFaces[count];
            PointF midPoint=new PointF();
            face.getMidPoint(midPoint);

            eyeDistance=face.eyesDistance();
            canvas.drawRect(midPoint.x-eyeDistance, midPoint.y-eyeDistance, midPoint.x+eyeDistance, midPoint.y+eyeDistance, myPaint);
        }
    }

 }
}
```

this code will detects the face from Bitmap so you should implement this technique also through camera 
cheers .

Comment: let me know if u have any doubt

Comment: Thank you sir, and what do you think about following algorithms,
HOG, edge detection, Shift and mean shift.. and my proj is not only basis of detection also I've to match the face from a database. Thank you!